# UWP: Use Move instead of Remove+Insert when reordering items in ListView

Tags: listview, uwp

I'm using a [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview) control bound to an [ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.8). I've setup the control to support reordering items inside the collection with the following settings:

```
<ListView
    AllowDrop="True"
    CanDragItems="True"
    CanReorderItems="True">
    ...
</ListView>
```

It all works nicely, except I've noticed that despite the source collection supporting the [Move()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.move?view=netframework-4.8) method, the list view does Remove() + Insert() instead.

Problem is, I've also implemented Undo-Redo functionality on the collection by responding to CollectionChanged events. And since the list view performs two actions instead of one, I need to Undo twice to get to the state before the move. On the other hand, if I call the Move() method on the collection via code, only one Undo is needed (as it should be).

So my question is: How can I force the list view to use the Move() method?

Answer (score 4):

> So my question is: How can I force the list view to use the Move() method?

**The current ListView does not provide a property or method that supports this operation.**

The data source of `ListView` is not necessarily `ObservableCollection`, it can be an array, List or other collection, and these collections may do not have `Move()` method.

But most collections are support the `Remove` and `Insert` methods. When the `ListView` performs data reordering, calling the `Remove` and `Insert` methods is the best choice.

The `Move` method of the `ObservableCollection` is also implemented based on this. According to the current open source **.Net Core**, I found the [implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.ObjectModel/src/System/Collections/ObjectModel/ObservableCollection.cs) of `ObservableCollection.Move`.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Called by base class ObservableCollection&lt;T&gt; when an item is to be moved within the list;
/// raises a CollectionChanged event to any listeners.
/// </summary>
protected virtual void MoveItem(int oldIndex, int newIndex)
{
    CheckReentrancy();

    T removedItem = this[oldIndex];

    base.RemoveItem(oldIndex);
    base.InsertItem(newIndex, removedItem);

    OnIndexerPropertyChanged();
    OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move, removedItem, newIndex, oldIndex);
}
```

*And here is the [implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/objectmodel/observablecollection.cs,270a83d222656b02) of the .Net Framework.(Almost the same)*

Although UWP does not have open source, there is no fundamental difference.

It can be seen that even the `ObservableCollection` uses the `Remove` and `Insert` methods internally, so the `ListView` does not deliberately emphasize the use of the `ObservableCollection.Move` method to adjust the position of the elements in the collection.

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The problem is, Move(), even though it calls Remove() and Insert() behind the scenes, raises only one OnCollectionChanged event, but Remove() + Insert() from ListView raises 2 events. Of course, I can modify my own code to be able to handle this situation, but I was hoping there is a way to make ListView call Move() directly.

Comment: I believe this is a meaningful attempt, but `ListView` does not provide a method or event to interfere with reordering.